# How can add played videos in my second listview?

Tags: android

I have two listview in two tabs. I want to show only played videos from my first default listview in to my second listview. How can i do this ? I am very new in android development. Any help will be precious. Thnks in advance.

Comment: you need a simple table in a database, keep records of played one in that...and fetch data to show in second list view.
Now search for "USING DATABASE IN ANDROID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following steps to achieve this.

1. Create a Database in separate class with a table name what you like.
2. Now insert the index of the played video with the name of the video in table.
3. Now when you will reach to your next activity fetch those records from table and show them in list view.

Also take a look at a [SQLite Database turoial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).